# Jboss RabbitMQ Error: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'rabbit:listener-container'

Tags: spring, jboss, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

Not sure what I'm missing here and couldn't search for a solution. Please help in solving this issue. Appreciate it.

It's running on Jboss EAP 6.3.0. Once I start the server, the logs just keep rolling and I need to stop it forcibly. The logs roll upto 20000kb-30000kb in seconds

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/das-jmsListener]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) JBWEB000289: Servlet springDispatcher threw load() exception: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 34; columnNumber: 109; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'rabbit:listener-container'.
```

Here is the Spring-context xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
                           classpath:org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-4.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit-1.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.poc.sample" />

    <bean id="das-DataZoneConverter" class="com.poc.sample.amqp.converters.DataZoneRemoteMessageConverter">
        <property name="oxmUtil" ref="oxmUtility" />
    </bean>

    <!-- config for each service 
        Each service will require 2 beans :
        #listener
        #listenerContainer                          
    -->

    <!-- config start -->

 <rabbit:listener-container id="userService-listenerContainer" connection-factory="connectionFactory">
        <rabbit:listener ref="userService-listener" queues="userService-RequestQueue" />
    </rabbit:listener-container>

    <!-- config end -->

</beans>
```

Here is a snapshot of pom.xml:

```
<!-- Rabbit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-amqp</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.amqp.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.amqp.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
            <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
            <version>${rabbitmq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

**EDIT:**

1. I removed all the version numbers in the schema.
2. AMQP version:

> rabbitmq.version 3.1.1
>
> spring.amqp.version 1.1.4.RELEASE

3. I recently changed the webapp (web.xml) from 2.4 to 3.0. Would that be an issue. I never tested if it worked before the change. Will this matter?

**EDIT: These errors below no longer appear in the error. The only error is still the matching wildcard**

4. I see a few more errors in the log (they keep repeating). These errors occured earlier too:

> ```
> 09:57:02,246 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/cdat]]
> ```
>
> (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) JBWEB000287: Exception sending
>   context initialized event to listener instance of class
>   com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener:
>   `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBAS011857: NamingStore is null`
>         at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.(NamingContext.java:152)
>         at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.(NamingContext.java:125)
>         at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext$DefaultInitialContext.(InitialContext.java:182)
>         at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:117)
>         at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:154)
>         at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>         at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>         at com.sun.faces.config.WebConfiguration.processJndiEntries(WebConfiguration.java:702)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
>         at com.sun.faces.config.WebConfiguration.(WebConfiguration.java:134)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
>         at com.sun.faces.config.WebConfiguration.getInstance(WebConfiguration.java:194)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
>         at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:158)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339)
>   [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777)
>   [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
>         at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:161)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
>         at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:59)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
>         at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:94)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
>         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>         at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)

And this:

```
09:57:02,733 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./cdat: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./cdat: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:97)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:166)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:59)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:94)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: You don't show your `spring.amqp.version` but this error typically means spring cannot locate the schema on the classpath so it's generally a classpath issue.

Comment: Please, make your schema location as `versionless`. The framework picks up the latest XSD from its jar in that case.

Comment: Can you please review my edits and let me know if I'm missing anything else.